# Azure query consumption from the command line

Tags: azure-devops

I want to see azure resource consumption from the command line.

I found this subcommand: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/consumption/usage?view=azure-cli-latest, but I'm getting errors:

```
az consumption usage --start-date 2021-10-01 --end-date 2021-11-02
'2021-10-01' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.

TRY THIS:
https://aka.ms/cli_ref
Read more about the command in reference docs
```

I don't understand this because the documentation says "Start date (YYYY-MM-DD in UTC)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the *list* command after the 'consumption usage' statement.

The following statement works on Azure CLI version 2.30.0:

`az consumption usage list --start-date 2021-10-01 --end-date 2021-11-01`

> List the details of Azure resource consumption, either as an invoice or within a billing period.

[az consumption usage list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/consumption/usage?view=azure-cli-latest#az_consumption_usage_list)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try passing the dates in between quotation marks?

```
az consumption usage --start-date "2021-10-01" --end-date "2021-11-02"
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this out, but it returns the same error.